# Unable to locate a file in java project running in a executable jar

Tags: java, executable-jar

Both `class.getResource(FILE_NAME)` and `class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME)` run perfectly inside my eclipse but the same code getting failed to locate the file which is inside the jar file, when run as an executable jar in windows machine.

I have gone through all related links available for this problem (well, not exactly the same issue but 90% in sync), asked for solution but no reply came from any of those posts, so I'm posting my issue as a separate question hoping for help on this.

In total, 4 cases I have ran to resolve but none worked so far and I'm out of ideas now.

```
class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/readme.txt");
class.getResource("/resources/readme.txt");
class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/readme.txt");
class.getResource("resources/readme.txt");
```

Ouf of all the above 4 cases, only 2 cases ran successfully in eclipse which are as mentioned below.

```
class.getResource("/resources/readme.txt");
class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/readme.txt");
```

The other 2 cases just throwing me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Coming to the executable jar, all 4 cases are throwing me the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`.

So I have created a folder named `resources` where my jar is residing and placed my files inside this folder and ran the jar. Now the jar is running without any issues referring to the files inside the `resources` folder I created. So wherever I run this jar (windows, linux etc.,) I need to create a `resources` folder and place my files under the folder. Now the question is, can it be possible to make my jar refer the `resources` folder which is inside the jar itself?

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is it that is throwing NullPointerException? It can't be the `Class.getResource()` method – that only ever throws an exception if you pass it a null argument, which you're not doing. So it must be something inside your own code. Is the `Class.getResource()` method returning null and you're not checking if it's null?

Comment: when `getResource()` is unable to locate the file, it will throw `NullPointerException` in general

Comment: No, it will not throw NullPointerException unless you pass it a null argument. If it cannot locate the resource, it will return null. As it says in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: My bad, I got confused with null and NullPointerException. Yes, it is returning null when it is unable to locate the file and on top of null I'm trying further operations which is throwing me NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you see your readme.txt file if you look at the executable jar file in a zip viewer (such as 7-zip, winzip, winrar etc) or if you give the command `jar -tf yourfile.jar`?

Comment: yes, when I unzip it, I'm able to see resources folder and readme.txt file under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get your txt file:**

```
File yourFileIsHere = new File("resources/readme.txt");
```

**Where put your file?**

In the same location of your jar, example:

> myapp/yourjar.jar
>
> myapp/resources/readme.txt

**If you want read file inside of your "src" folder:**

```
InputStream yourInputStream = new YourClass().getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("readme.txt");
```

Comment: `resources` folder is under src folder

Comment: when I export my project as jar, it will be `myapp.jar` and my file will be inside the jar

Comment: `InputStream yourInputStream = new YourClass().getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("readme.txt");` will only work if the file `readme.txt` is inside the src folder directly. But my `readme.txt` is under src\resources folder

Comment: Just remember: if your file be inside any folder into "src", you must have specify the path, example: "folder_inside_src/readme.txt"

Comment: Use: InputStream yourInputStream = new YourClass().getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/readme.txt");

Comment: Can you help me on how to pass the object `yourInputStream` to `FileOutputStream' class?

Comment: Sure, exists many ways to do that, let's a simple way, without any library:   byte[] bytes = new byte[yourInputStream.available()];
  yourInputStream.read(bytes);
  yourInputStream.close(); //close inputstream, bytes already readed.
  
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("your_path_file"));
  fos.write(bytes);
  fos.close(); //close fileoutputstream.

Comment: Unfortunately the above code is not throwing any error which is good but my content is not getting written into `readme.txt` file this way.

Comment: Hold on, you want to *write* to readme.txt? You can't. Once the file is in the jar, it's read-only.

Comment: Yes, DodgyCodeException is right. You can't write in file inside the jar. If you would like it, create the external folder to make it.

Comment: Thanks a ton DodgyCodeException and @BrunoCarletti for sparing your valuable time in clarifying me on what is not possible here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring:

```
org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:readme.txt")
```

Otherwise:

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources

byte[] byteSource = Resources.asByteSource(Resources.getResource("readme.txt")).read()
```

Comment: Not using Spring, so will try out the Otherwise option you mentioned. Can you help me on how to pass the object `byteSource` to `FileOutputStream' class?

Answer (score 0):

method `class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` may take 3 prefixes: `url:`, `classpath:` and `file:` each prefix tells what is your base of search. If you want to search inside your jar use `classpath:` prefix. That tells your classloader to search everywhere within your classpath. Here is one [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/) how to deal with it with Spring tools. Look also at [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) class in Spring

Comment: how do I use `classpath:` prefix?. Sorry, I'm not using Spring here, this is only a java project I'm using.

Comment: I believe that classloader also accepts those prefixes. As to how to use prefix - instead of 
class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/readme.txt");
use
class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("classpath:resources/readme.txt");

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name`

Comment: try to remove leading slash:
class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/readme.txt");

Comment: I haven't used any leading slash at all

Comment: @MichaelGantman Are you sure that [Class.getResource(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) supports the prefixes `url:`, `classpath:` and `file:`? Since you provided the JavaDoc for the complete differed class [ResourceLoader.getResource(String location)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Well, I thought it did as well, but now I remember that I worked with it work Spring classes, for which I provided Javadoc references. I actually tried it for regular classloader and it didn't work for me. So I guess I was wrong in this one